# What does "with us and through" mean?

Tags: meaning

> We, and our affiliates, third party service providers, and trusted
>   partners send "cookies" to your device or use similar technologies to
>   understand and enhance your online experience **with us and through** our
>   advertising and media across the Internet including Social Media
>   Sites, mobile apps, and video games.
>   (http://www.mobeegaming.com/PRIVACY.html)

Does the bold part mean "your online experience with us and your online experience through out advertising ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means pretty much what you say. It’s not exactly the heights of excellence in prose, but Mobe are making two assertions:

1. They are using cookies to enhance your online experience while using their site

And

2. They are using cookies to enhance your online experience through the use of advertising, social media, and so on.

And since there is so much commonality, they smoosh the two together with that “and” conjunction.

But as I say, it’s not very well written. For a start, the second of the above essentially contains the first. But I can’t imagine they expected anyone to do them the honour of paying as much attention to their privacy notice as you have.